# Redirecting to the self page in a loop & processing data

Tags: php, http-headers

I'm processing some data from external pages. The pages can be accessed sequentially, i.e **http://localhost/info/1.html, http://localhost/info/2.html, http://localhost/info/3.html, ....**

```
<?php
$id = 0;
$id = intval($_GET['id'])+1;
$url = 'http://localhost/info/'.$id.'.html';

if (!$html = @file_get_contents($url)) {
  $url = 'http://localhost/crawler.php?id='.$id;
  //header("Location: ".$url);
  echo '<html><script>window.location.href = "'.$url.'";</script>    </html>';
  die();
}

//process data

$url = 'http://localhost/crawler.php?id='.$id;
//header("Location: ".$url);
echo '<html><script>window.location.href = "'.$url.'";</script></html>';
die();
?>
```

The problem is the PHP redirect stops showing error ***the page is not redirecting properly***, and redirect using JavaScript looks like slower. Already tried using header with removing the echo.

**

### Is there any way to speed up the process ?

**

Comment: `PHP redirect`  Such as `header('Location:` only works if you have not sent any headers, this includes the Content-type header that gets sent when you output HTML or other things.

Comment: Typically a better way to handle something like this is to use AJAX, you can have a UI page, that makes an AJAX call to the server to do the processing, then you send a response back to the AJAX success callback, that calls the next AJAX request (which creates your loop).  That way you can avoid the redirects all together.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I had tried only the header option without "echo" still does not work !

Comment: You mean without, print_r, var_export, var_dump, print, echo or whitespace (or anything) before/after your `<?php` tags throughout the entire execution stack...  Any whitespace even a single space before a open or after a close PHP tag can kill header redirect.  In otherwords any output at all.  `Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP` http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: @artisticPhoenix can you help me build that Ajax - UI part ?

Comment: No, as I don't have time for it. Sorry.